# Is there an app that will make my (jailbroken) iPhone vibrate when a call is answered?

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation, jailbreak

I have an jailbroken iPhone and I want it to make a little vibration when the other participant answer the call so I don't have to hold it near to my ear while the phone is dialing.
I found this feature in **MCleaner** app from Cydia but it costs too much and have a lot of other features that I don't need. Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you want it to do. Why would you hold it to your ear while dialing, and what does that have to do with vibrating on answering a call?

Comment: @deceze although it’s a weird question, it’s easy to understand. There’s an app on Cydia that lets you dial a number and wait without having to put the phone in your ear or use the speaker. It will simply vibrate when the other party has picked up the phone, so you can put it next to your ear to -presumably- talk.

Comment: @Martín If you put it that way... It's hard to understand from the way the OP put it. :)

Comment: @deceze English foreign speakers ;)

Comment: @Mar, @dec: I think the confusion is with the word "dialing" which usually means pressing the numbers on a phone to place a call. I think a better word is "ringing" in this case. Additionally, it would help if it said that the "call answer" is referring to the other person answering the call, not you. The way I first understood it, I thought it was a weird request to have the phone vibrate every time I press "answer" to pick up a call.

Comment: I rephrased it a bit. I hope that's okay for you, @Semyon

Answer (score 2):

As someone who is involved in some iPhone developing, I can tell you that you can’t do that with the official SDK, so unless you find another Jailbroken app, there’s no “official” way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Get Phone Buzzer from Cydia, it works brilliantly, and its free.

Answer (score 0):

Hey make sure in your settings that you have a vibration selected.... I thought I had the same issue until I realized that a type of vibration wasn't selected.
 jonlo